# Barrier Option Valuation

Tags: options, option-pricing, risk-neutral-measure

Good day,

> A **reverse knock-out barrier call option** expires worthless if the asset
>   price ever goes above a given barrier level. Calculate the value of this
>   barrier option struck at $K = 3$ with barrier level $B = 9$.
>
> Also, explain why the barrier call option worth less than the vanilla call?
>
> $r=0$

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& S(t=0,\omega) & S(t=1,\omega)^* & S(t=2,\omega)^* &S(t=3,\omega)^* \\ \hline
\omega_1 & 5& 8& 11 &15\\ \hline
\omega_2 & 5& 8& 11 &10\\ \hline
\omega_3 & 5& 8& 7 &10\\ \hline
\omega_4 & 5& 8& 7 &5\\ \hline
\omega_5 & 5& 4& 7 &10\\ \hline
\omega_6 & 5& 4& 7 &5\\ \hline
\omega_7 & 5& 4& 2 &5\\ \hline
\omega_8 & 5& 4& 2 &1\\ \hline
\end{array}

I found risk neutral probabilities for each path and at each node and I think I am correct (hard to go wrong as $r=0$ and no dividends are paid.I calculated the value of a vanilla call option using dynamic programming but Im not quite sure how to approach the Barrier option valuation. Do I simply put the paths with over $9$ to be equal to $0$ and apply dynamic programming again?

The additional question; its worth less as there is a range of values for which the option is worth anything whereas a vanilla option has only a minimum.

Comment: What is the payout if this option if the value hasn't gone above the barrier level?

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if your question has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer I ***assume*** that $K$ is the strike and the payoff at time t=3 is $X$:

$X=
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 (S_3-K)^+ & \text{if }S_1,S_2,S_3\leq9 \\
 0 & \text{ else } \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$

Please correct me if I am mistaking.

**The answer to your question is yes**! The pay-offs are given as
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
& \text{Pay-Off} \\ \hline
\omega_1 & 0 \\ \hline
\omega_2 & 0 \\ \hline
\omega_3 & 0 \\ \hline
\omega_4 & 2 \\ \hline
\omega_5 & 0 \\ \hline
\omega_6 & 2 \\ \hline
\omega_7 & 2 \\ \hline
\omega_8 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Naturally the the payoff of the option has an upper bound $B-K$ and the vanilla call does not have this bound, so the the vanilla is worth more. This is pretty trivial.
Even if $S_3<B$ then there is a probability that the $S_t>B$ for $t<3$. This fact will also push the price at $t=0$ down compared to vanilla call.